# Change CSS with JavaScript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a CSS "button" that is covering some table rows.  Each time you click it, it reveals the next row.  Upon revealing the last row, the text is changed to DONE!  The script below makes all of this happen and it's working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var last = $('tbody tr:hidden').length;
    if (last > 0) {
        $("#nextStep").click(function () {
            var x = $("tbody tr:hidden:first");

            console.log(x);
            console.log(last);
            $("tbody tr:hidden:first").show();
            last = $('tbody tr:hidden').length;
            if (last == 0) { 
                $("#nextStep").html('DONE!');
                $("#nextStep").css('cursor', 'default');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I'd like to add in the following: When the text is changed to DONE!, I also want the background to change colors.  The CSS that is applied to this button is...

```
.show_next_button {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #79bbff), color-stop(1, #378de5) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#79bbff', endColorstr='#378de5');
    background-color:#79bbff;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #222529;
    //display:inline-block;
    //display:table-cell;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:bold;
    //padding-left:20%;
    //padding-right:20%;
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #4c6d8f;
}
.show_next_button:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #378de5), color-stop(1, #79bbff) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#378de5', endColorstr='#79bbff');
    background-color:#378de5;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.show_next_button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: $("#nextStep").css('background-color', 'red'); doesnt work?

Comment: also you could combine 
                $("#nextStep").html('DONE!');
                $("#nextStep").css('cursor', 'default'); to be 
                $("#nextStep").html('DONE!').css('cursor', 'default'); this would increase performance slightly

Comment: @ Seth McClaine: No, your 1st comment doesn't work.  I also tried implementing your 1st comment with your 2nd and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class a with the new background color, and then add it

```
.completed-step {
 background-color: pink;
 cursor: default;
}

// replace the call to '$("#nextStep").css('cursor', 'default');'
$("#nextStep").addClass("completed-step");
```

here's an example
http://jsfiddle.net/ED4Zt/1/

Comment: the gradient classes are preventing the new background color from being displayed, it works if you remove complicated css class, you can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/ED4Zt/1/

Comment: You're right.  I was just about to post a reply saying that it did work, but it's more complicated than just changing the background color.  BTW, the jsfiddle isn't displaying anything for me.  Thanks for the help!