# How to change css pseudo-element through javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My webpage randomly generates a color, and some elements, like inputs, get colors generated as border or so through javascript. Something like this:

```
document.getElementById('input').style.color = color;
```

The thing is I want a thumb from `<input type="range" />` to get the random color generated and I don't know how to do it, tried and searched the web without finding a solution to get this css style `input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb` in javascript.

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pseudo elements cannot be changed via javascript.. You will have to use JQuery `addClass` and `removeClass`

Comment: Nooooooo! thanks @imbondbaby, my worst fears came true. At least I don't need to search more

Comment: You could try this? http://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change CSS with Javascript (jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509263/change-css-with-javascript-jquery)

Comment: you can always add a `style` block to your head with javascript, which can target the pseudo elements.

Comment: I already read that, but I don't need to get their properties, I want to change their property, thanks anyway for trying @joshhunt .

Comment: Oh ok, your question makes it sound like you just need to get it.

Comment: @imbondbaby so if it cannot be done via javascript, then how does jquery does it....

Comment: @mightyuhu Sorry couldn't edit my comment it can be done in both by adding and removing class

Comment: See [Setting CSS pseudo-class rules from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript). It's the same for pseudo-elements.

Comment: basically this is bad software design. you should have no need to query the pseudo selector from javascript. do you need the value of the range input?

Comment: No need to get the value of the range input why @mightyuhu?

Comment: @AstroCB no, my question it's not answered in that question, but thanks anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I finally did it, I don't know if what I did is good programming but anyway it works, I needed to add a css rule so by doing this:

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb 
{ background-color:' + color + ' !important; }', 0);
```

I was able to finally manipulate the pseudo-element (at least in chrome, next step other major browsers).
Anyway I think this is helpful to someone who wants to try something like this, I needed to search and tried many things to do this.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to change the style of a pseudo-element is by adding and removing classes in JavaScript or JQuery. Here is an example:

**CSS:**

```
.newClass::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    color:red;
}
```

**JS Solution:**

To add class:

```
document.getElementById("selector").classList.add('newClass');
```

To remove class:

```
document.getElementById("selector").classList.remove('newClass');
```

**JQuery Solution:**

To add class:

```
$("#selector").addClass("newClass");
```

To remove class:

```
$("#selector").removeClass("newClass");
```

Comment: So using this how can I add my js variable 'color' to this new class?

Comment: Thanks anyway you gave me hope @imbondbaby.